# Error when creating ASP.NET MVC 3 project with xUnit: xunit.targets not found

Tags: visual-studio-2010, xunit, xunit.net

I create an ASP.NET MVC 3 project and a unit test project using xUnit.net.

[new project http://img841.imageshack.us/img841/38/newprojectsnt.png](http://img841.imageshack.us/img841/38/newprojectsnt.png)

But I got an error like this, and the unit test project is not created.

[error http://img15.imageshack.us/img15/4725/errordp.png](http://img15.imageshack.us/img15/4725/errordp.png)

Does anyone know how to fix it? I'm using Visual Studio 2010 Professional SP1, on Windows 8 Release Preview.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem while using version 1.9.1 (Jul 4 2012 release). I uninstalled it and installed the version 1.9 (Jul 4 2012 release)and now it is working fine. I'm using Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate SP1 and Windows 7 Ultimate with SP1.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry about this bug. We're planning to remove template support from 2.0 anyway, so this bug is going to go away.

Moving forward, we recommend people just create class libraries, and bring in xunit.dll via NuGet.